# how to disable an image button on occurance of an event in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

this is my code...

```
<input type="image" src="../../Content/images/add_icon.png" title="Create Group"
                               id ="IMGaddicon" onclick="return EnableTextBox(event);" />
```

this has to get disabled when the following event occurs

```
function addgroup(event, groupName) {
    var groupid = 0;
    var SaveCollection = [];
    var GroupName = "";
    if (groupName != "") {
        GroupName = groupName;
    } else {
        GroupName = savegroupname;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: GroupSave,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {
            GroupID: groupid,
            GroupName: GroupName,
            SaveValues: $.toJSON(SaveCollection)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var groupgrid = $('#grouping').data('kendoGrid');
            groupgrid.dataSource._data[0].GroupID = data.GroupID;
            saveflag = false;
            groupflag = false;
            GroupNames = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < groupgrid.dataSource._data.length; i++) {
                GroupNames.push({
                    Text: groupgrid.dataSource._data[i].GroupName,
                    Id: groupgrid.dataSource._data[i].GroupID
                });
            }
            GroupingMenuRelaod(GroupNames);
            groupgrid.clearSelection();
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: What has to get disabled when what happens? This doesn't make much sense!

Comment: What is the error? which thing you want to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in ur event.

```
function addgroup(event, groupName) {
    $("#IMGaddicon").attr('disabled','disabled');
    var groupid = 0;
    var SaveCollection = [];
    var GroupName = "";   
    // Rest of ur code
});
```

//To Enable the Button, put following code in your event :-

```
$("#IMGaddicon").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Thanx buddy it works... What should i do to enable it back when another event has occured?